# Debian computer does not wake up monitor

Tags: debian, video, hibernate

I have a Debian system that I leave unattended for long periods. Recently I plugged in a video HDMI and it did not activate the screen. I am pretty sure from the lights the system was functioning, its just that it was not activating the video card. I tried unplugging and re-plugging it, with no luck. I ended up power cycling the machine which is not good.

Debian has the following note:

> **Fixing corrupted video on resume**
>
> A very common issue found after the computer resumes is corrupted
>   video (or black screen, or no LCD backlight). The first step is to
>   check whether the system is still running, which can be simply done by
>   pressing the Capslock button and check whether the Capslock LED is
>   changing accordingly. If the system is still running, in most cases we
>   need to add a video quirk for your video card.
>
> Debian now has kernel mode setting (KMS) enabled by default for most
>   Intel, nVidia and ATI video cards. But pm-utils' video quirk does
>   support KMS yet. So in most cases you should try disabling KMS first.
>   The detail steps for your specific video card can be found on the
>   KernelModesetting page.
>
> After disabled KMS, if the video after resume still corrupts, you can
>   try to suspend the system by using some video quirks. Read the manpage
>   of the pm-suspend program for a very detail explanation of all the
>   quirks available, and try the combinations of them from commandline.
>   If you successfully find one combination of quirks that works for your
>   system, you can add them into /usr/lib/pm-utils/video-quirks to make
>   them permanent. At the same time, please help to file a bug against
>   the pm-utils package with a patch about your changes so it can benefit
>   the mass.
>
> A common issue found on systems upgrading from old versions of Debian
>   is the enabling of quirk-s3-bios freezes the system during suspend. If
>   your system freezes during suspend, check the pm-suspend.log carefully
>   after enabled debugging and make sure quirk-s3-bios is not used.

I don't really get from this how to avoid the problem in the future.

How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: You quoted an (old) note about resume-from-sleep. But you didn't seem to actually mention anything about having suspended your PC in the first place – only that it suddenly froze after connecting a HDMI cable, which is a completely different situation.

Comment: @grawity No, it didn't freeze, the monitor just didn't come on. Normally, when I plug in the monitor and move the mouse or hit the space bar, the monitor comes on. It did not come on, which means the video is stuck in hibernate.

Comment: Did you try to SSH into the machine? It doesn't mean that your "video is stuck in hibernate" it could also just mean that an output process crashed or that for some reason your graphics card/the driver didn't recognize that a new display was attached.

Comment: @Seth That is why I was using the monitor in the first place. My internet connection get knocked out by a storm and when that happens the IP address changes. So, I have to get onto the physical system to find out the new IP address.